# Create a MATLAB function that estimates e and outlines the error

Tags: matlab, if-statement, while-loop

I'm attempting to create a function that provides me with an estimate of e(`exp(1)`), and that provides me with information about the error within the function.
Estimating e was not an issue, however, when attempting to use an `if` statement created an infinite recursion within my function.

Here is my function

```
function e = myExpFunction(i)
for i = 1:20
    n = 10.^i;
    e = (1+1./n).^n;
    if abs(exp(1) - myExpFunction(i)) < abs(exp(1) - myExpFunction(i-1))
        fprintf('The error always decreases as n increases.\n')    
    end
end
end
```

And here is the error message

```
myExpFunction(i)
Out of memory. The likely cause is an infinite recursion within the program.

Error in myExpFunction (line 5)
    if abs(exp(1) - myExpFunction(i)) < abs(exp(1) - myExpFunction(i-1))
```

I have tried using a `while` loop to bound the value of i between 1 and 20 but got the same error message. So I suppose I must have created an infinite loop within those bounds.

I'm having trouble fixing this as I don't understand where in the program I have created an infinite recursion. If anyone could help me out and shed some light it would be a massive help, thanks.

Comment: (1) Please don't use `i` or `j` as varible names, since these are reserved for the imaginary unit, cf. [`i`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/i.html). (2) With every call of `myExpFunction`, you start a `for i = 1:20` ignoring the passed `i` and inside calling (again) `myExpFunction(i)`, so that's an infinite recursion.

Comment: @HansHirse (1) `i` and `j` are not reserved; MATLAB handles shadowing perfectly efficiently. I agree it's good practice to avoid shadowing such names but even MATLAB official documentation uses `i` as a loop index in places and this is not Code Review SE. (2) This should be an answer, not a comment on the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I understood the problem. In "If" you are calling the function you are in, you must call the variable "e(i)" and "e(i-1)" to avoid the infinite loop.

```
function e = myExpFunction(i)

e(1) = (1+1/10)^10
for i = 2:20
    n = 10.^i;
    e(i) = (1+1/n)^n;
    if abs(exp(1) - e(i)) < abs(exp(1) - e(i-1))
        fprintf('The error always decreases as n increases.\n')    
    end
end

end
```